# Stdin to child process in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to run the following on PhantomJS:

```
sqlite3 mydb.db < mysql.sql
```

Is this achievable with `spawn` or do I need to put it in a bash script and call the script?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't just use pipes as you would in a bash script, but you can pipe them manually in javascript. Take a look at [Streams](http://phantomjs.org/api/stream/) and [child_process](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/).

**Hint:** use `spawn().stdin.write` and `fs.openFile.read`.

Comment: No, you can't use pipes, because they are not implemented in PhantomJS. Node.js and PhantomJS have completely different execution environments.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I thought Phantomjs uses Nodejs. Answer updated.